# How to build "big" div structures in JavaScript (JQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I need to make big DIV structures and append them to a wrapper.
But what I've seen so far was always about appending **one** DIV element into another one.

There is an empty DIV-Wrapper, to be filled with "big" DIV-Elements

```
<div class="PostWrapper">
    // Content should be added to here
</div>
```

The DIV-Elements which I want to append to the `PostWrapper` look like this:

```
<div class="Post">
    <div class="PostHead">
         <span class="profilePicture">
             <img src="../Profiles/Tom.jpg" />
         </span>
         <span class="userName">Tom</span>
         <span class="postTime">10 minutes ago</span>
    </div>
    <div class="PostBody">
        <p>Hey Tom, great work at the presentation last week. Well done!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So this is an example of a DIV-Structure which I'd like to build and store in a javascript Variable and append to my wrapper like:

```
var postElement = $("div", {class: "Post"}).append("div", {class: "PostHead"}).append("div", {class: "PostBody"})......
```

This wont work like expected ofc. But I can't think of a simple way of doing this without having overly complexe code.

How would that be possible?

Comment: You need to nest them. Otherwise, you're appending each element to `Post`, not the element inside it. Or try reversing them and using `.appendTo`.

Comment: For anything complex, use a HTML template. That can be as simple as a dummy script block, with an id, that uses an unknown type so the browser ignore it (I use `text/template`). You then just use the inner `html()` of the element to create the new structure. Much easier to read/maintain and less error prone. Example added below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anything complex, use a HTML template. That can be as simple as a dummy script block, with an id, that uses an unknown type so the browser ignore it (I use text/template). You then just use the inner `html()` of the element to create the new structure. Much easier to read/maintain and less error prone

Example html:

```
<script id="mytemplate" type="text/template">
    <div class="Post">
        <div class="PostHead">
             <span class="profilePicture">
                 <img src="../Profiles/Tom.jpg" />
             </span>
             <span class="userName">Tom</span>
             <span class="postTime">10 minutes ago</span>
        </div>
        <div class="PostBody">
            <p>Hey Tom, great work at the presentation last week. Well done!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
```

then create one with:

```
$('.PostWrapper').append($('#mytemplate').html());
```

note: *If they need dynamic values anywhere, use text replacement markers in the template and string replaces.*

e.g.

```
<script id="mytemplate" type="text/template">
    <div class="Post">
        <div class="PostHead">
             <span class="profilePicture">
                 <img src="{image}" />
             </span>
             <span class="userName">{name}</span>
             <span class="postTime">{posted}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="PostBody">
            <p>{notes}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
```

Or simply add those details once the template has been added to the DOM.

Comment: Nice. Looks like a clear and maintainable way of doing this. Thx :)

Comment: Its the maintenance ease and readability that attracted me to this type of solution. Too many human errors with HTML in strings! :)

Comment: FWIW, IMHO you should use `.clone` not `.html`.  `.html()` should _only_ be used for constructing new elements, and never for copying them nor for performing read/modify/update operations.

Comment: @Alnitak: I don't think elements in a script block are DOM elements. So `clone` would not work. You could use a hidden div with `clone` instead.

Comment: Ah yes, of course that's true for a `script` block - although in that case one should probably use `.innerText` or `.textContent` instead.  What I wrote above still applies in most other cases.

Comment: @hAlnitak: I prefer `.html()` in this case as it's the "jQuery" way and there can't be anything else in the script block and `.html()` has one line of code in it (`return element.innerHTML;`) so is quite efficient.

Comment: Ok not sure what I'm doing wrong but `$('#mytemplate').html()` returns `""` for me :/ my template declaration: `<script id="mytemplate" type="text/template" src="~/Scripts/PostTemplate.js"></script>`

Answer (score 5):

You can mostly do what you want just by ensuring that you call `$(...)` for each new element you want to create:

```
var postElement = $("<div>", {class: "Post"}).append(
   $("<div>", {class: "PostHead"}).append( /* head contents */ ),
   $("<div>", {class: "PostBody"}).append( /* body contents */ )
);

$('#PostWrapper').append(postElement);
```

NB: `<div>` not `div`.  The former is used to create elements, the latter only to *select* them.

Comment: I don't think that works as expected. calling append after making a new element with `$("<div>", {class: "PostHead"})` would then be selected and `PostBody` would be a child of `PostHead`

Comment: @Future I hadn't looked at the HTML structure too closely - will amend.

Comment: @Future done that - `.append` will take a list of elements to add, so it's just a question of nesting the `.append` calls appropriately.

Comment: okay thanks, this looks good, and like you can cascade it even further :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use no `.append()` at all, and create an element from the entire html structure markup. Just have to escape newlines with an `\`

```
var postElement = $('<div class="Post"> \
    <div class="PostHead"> \
         <span class="profilePicture"> \
             <img src="../Profiles/Tom.jpg" /> \
         </span> \
         <span class="userName">Tom</span> \
         <span class="postTime">10 minutes ago</span> \
    </div> \
    <div class="PostBody"> \
        <p>Hey Tom, great work at the presentation last week. Well done!</p> \
    </div> \
</div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0089yghq/

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var $e1 = $("<div/>").addClass("Post");
var $e2 = $("<div/>").addClass("PostHead");
var $e3 = $("<div/>").addClass("PostBody");

var $s1 = $("<span/>").addClass("profilePicture");
var $s2 = $("<span/>").addClass("userName");
var $s3 = $("<span/>").addClass("postTime");

var $i = $("<img/>").attr("src","../Profiles/Tom.jpg");
var $p = $("<p/>").html("Hey Tom, great work at the presentation last week. Well done!");

var $myobj =  
  $e1.append( 
     $e2
       .append( $s1.append($i) ) 
       .append( $s2 ) 
       .append( $s3 ) 
  ) 
  .append( $e3.append( $p ) );

  //now append it to your html

  $myobj.appendTo("body");
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended doing a similar solution. Just in case someone find it useful.

```
<div>
    <div id="group">


    </div>
    <input type="button" class="btn btn principal" onclick="addRuleTo('group')" value="Add">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addRuleTo(element) {
        var randomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000);    //* a big number
        var template =
        '<div class="row" style="" id="{{randomId}}"> \
            <div class="col-md-3"></div> \
            <div class="col-md-3"></div> \
            <div class="col-md-5"></div> \
            <div class="col-md-1"><input type="button" class="btn btn-principal" onclick="removeRule({{randomId}})" value="X"></div> \
        </div>';

        template = template.replace(/{{randomId}}/g, randomId);    //global replacement

        $('#' + element).append(template);
    }
    function removeRule(ruleId) {
        $('div#' + ruleId).remove();
    }
</script>
```